# Recommended way to calulate time and display to user

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Just curious as to what people think is the best way to calculate how long a search takes and then display time to user.

I am using DateTime with Timespan and also Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch.

I think using Stopwatch is cleaner code compared to DateTime with timespan.

So I'm just curious as to what professional programmers use.

i.e

```
Stopwatch WebSearchTime = new Stopwatch();
WebSearchTime.Start();
code to run
WebSearchTime.Stop();
double WST = WebSearchTime.Elapsed.Seconds + (WebSearchTime.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 1000.0);
```

Thanks

George

Answer (score 2):

Stopwatch is the proper and [more accurate](http://jaychapman.blogspot.com/2007/12/datetimenow-precision-issues-enter.html) way to determine time of execution, than `DateTime.Now` with `DateTime` calculation.

[Stopwatch Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the
>   underlying timer mechanism. **If the installed hardware and operating
>   system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the
>   Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time.**
>   Otherwise, the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure
>   elapsed time. Use the Frequency and IsHighResolution fields to
>   determine the precision and resolution of the Stopwatch timing
>   implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I know that use of Stopwatch is preferred way but I created code snippets to use DateTime and used to use them:

```
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        //logic
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Comment:" + (DateTime.Now - start));
```

Sure if you need to aggregate results you'll have to create TimeSpan. Now I see whole lot of information being outputted while debugging.

My bad. I measured performance as VARAK suggested and it turned out that DateTime.Now takes about 0.00073ms to evaluate that could be real problem in production if you'll iterate over real big amounts of data so you should use my approach carefully.

Comment: This might be fine for debugging/testing but in PROD having DateTime.Nows all over the place is a bad idea as it is a very expensive operation

Comment: Good point, never thought about this.

Comment: Thanks all for comments, so best way is to stick with stopwatch